# How can I test requests per second locally?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple asp.net MVC application that I want to test how many requests per second the website can handle.

I'm on a windows computer, what tools can I use?

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: Bear in mind that regardless of the tool used, the answer you get is meaningless outside of the context of your own machine.  It will have little to no bearing on the number of requests per second you could expect out of a proper server setup.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Web Capacity Analysis Tool from Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231282/en-us

So if you are using...

IIS 6: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=17275

IIS 7: http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1466&g=6

Answer (score 1):

If you have an MSDN license and have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate you can take advantage of the  "web tests" and "load test" features.

You can create web tests to mimic the requests that you want to benchmark and then create a load test to tell VS how many users/network bandwidth/et cetera to emulate. Pretty neat stuff built into VS.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amit_chatterjee/archive/2009/01/29/web-and-load-testing-with-visual-studio-team-system.aspx